# Using BCP utility from R

Tags: sql, sql-server, r, bcp

Is it possible to use the BCP utility in R?

I'm currently using the RODBC package to read from a remote SQL server, but am experiencing slow transfer of data from `sqlFetch()` which could be alleviated with the use of BCP.

Comment: Just to be sure, you are referring to the SQL Server Bulk Copy utility known as `bcp`, not the R Bayesian Change Package..also known as bcp?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible.

First make sure you can run the BCP utility everywhere by including the path in the Environment Variables of Windows or you can use the full file path.

Then run:

```
shell("bcp dbName.dbo.tableName in mydata.csv -F 2 -S sqlSrvr -T -f bcp.fmt")
```

This should be exactly as if you were running it from the cmd prompt.

The hard part is setting up your data so it matches the format file.